# jQuery: Cloning the input value along with its style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append the value I have on an input on my first div to another div along with its css.
here's my HTML Code:

```
<div id="d1">
<input type="text" id="txt-initial" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 48px"/>
<input type="button" id="btn-clonetext" Value="clonetext">
</div>

<div id="d2" style="border:solid 1px; height: 400px; width: 400px; margin: 10px;">
</div>
```

Here's my JS Code:

```
$('#btn-clonetext').click(function(){
$('#d2').append($('#txt-initial').val());
})
```

if I use clone, the value is copied but so does the textbox; if I use val, the value is copied but not its style.

but val().clone() seems not to be working.
Any help? Thanks!

Comment: why dont you put the style properties in a class and then apply the class to input. then you can use this class and apply it to the div while copying the value.

Comment: Hmm, you got a point. but what if CSS is inside jQuery? Anyway, I'll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can help you, but it must be said that this is totally unnecessary. You can simply provide a class name and add styles via CSS.

```js
$('#btn-clonetext').click(function() {
  var $a = $('<div/>').text($('#txt-initial').val()).attr('style',$('#txt-initial').attr('style'))
  $('#d2').append($a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <input type="text" id="txt-initial" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 48px" />
  <input type="button" id="btn-clonetext" Value="clonetext">
</div>

<div id="d2" style="border:solid 1px; height: 400px; width: 400px; margin: 10px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying inline css to your `<input>` elemment having id **"txt-initial"** make a css class.
Now append this class in your jquery function.

```
<style>
  .txtInitialCss{
     font-family: Verdana; 
     font-size: 48px
   }
</style>


<div id="d1">
<input type="text" id="txt-initial" class='txtInitialCss'/>
<input type="button" id="btn-clonetext" Value="clonetext">
</div>

<div id="d2" style="border:solid 1px; height: 400px; width: 400px; margin: 10px;">
</div>

$('#btn-clonetext').click(function(){
$('#d2').append($('#txt-initial').val()).addClass("txtInitialCss");
})
```